# Very simple WF workflow expressed in Code

Tags: workflow-foundation

This question is really just to aid my understanding of Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) and how Workflows that I will create in XAML using the designer compare with what I could notionally do in code (I'm a programmer!).

Here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Activities;
using System.Activities.Statements;

namespace WorkflowConsoleApplication1
{
    public class CodeDefinedWorkflow : Activity
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invoking the workflow now");
            WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(new CodeDefinedWorkflow());
        }

        public CodeDefinedWorkflow()
        {
            Sequence s = new Sequence
            {
                Activities = {
                                new WriteLine {Text = "Hello"},
                                new Sequence 
                                {
                                    Activities =
                                    {
                                        new WriteLine {Text = "Workflow"},
                                        new WriteLine {Text = "World"}
                                    }
                                }
                             }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect the `WriteLine` activities to write text to the console (the default?).

I must be missing some way of adding the root `Sequence` activity. I've also tried making it a property and trying to find some way of initialising the component.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer!

Remove the contents of the constructor - and there is a property to override:

```
    protected override Func<Activity> Implementation
    {
        get
        {
            return () =>
                {
                    Sequence s = new Sequence
                        {
                            Activities = {
                                        new WriteLine {Text = "Hello"},
                                        new Sequence 
                                        {
                                            Activities =
                                            {
                                                new WriteLine {Text = "Workflow"},
                                                new WriteLine {Text = "World"}
                                            }
                                        }
                                     }
                        };
                    return s;
                };

        }
        set
        {
            base.Implementation = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or assign the object s created in the constructor to the base.Implementation property.